# How to ignore node unsupported engine when trying to install node modules?

Tags: node.js, npm

> ~/Documents/codecommit/Main  on rtspcheck   npm i nodemon
>  ✔  npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine { npm WARN EBADENGINE
> package: 'got@5.7.1', npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node:
> '>=0.10.0 <7' }, npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.3.0',
> npm: '7.16.0' } npm WARN EBADENGINE }
>
> up to date, audited 296 packages in 3s
>
> found 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: It's possible this is related to your npm version. Did you recently change versions, or forget perhaps to use nvm to force the nodeJS version you wanted?